# How do I generalize explicit formulae that have have numbers in them that create an arithmetic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

For example, If I have
$$
a_n=\frac{4(3^n)-1}{5}\\ 
b_n=\frac{6(3^n)-1}{5}\\
c_n=\frac{8(3^n)-1}{5}\\
$$

Clearly $4,6,8 \ldots$ have the explicit formula $2(n+1)$

So how would I generalize these explicit formulae knowing this arithmetic sequence? Is there a mathematical concept or notation that deals with something like this?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you saying you have a sequence of *sequences*, where the $n$-th term of the $m$-th sequence is given by $\frac{2(m+1)}{5} \left[3^n - 1\right]$ -- what would you like to know?

Comment: An "arithmetic sequence" has a common difference between consecutive entries.  In the example above, $6-4$ equals $8-6$, and so (if the sequence is indeed of this form), the explicit formula must be $2m + k$ for suitable initial value $k$.  But I suspect you already know that.

Answer (score 1):

You have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_n=\frac{4(3^n)-1}{5}\\ 
b_n=\frac{6(3^n)-1}{5}\\
c_n=\frac{8(3^n)-1}{5}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Lets rewrite them as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{n,1}=\frac{4(3^n)-1}{5}\\ 
a_{n,2}=\frac{6(3^n)-1}{5}\\
a_{n,3}=\frac{8(3^n)-1}{5}\\
\vdots
\end{eqnarray*}
& now we can summarise these into one equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{n,m}=\frac{2(m+1)(3^n)-1}{5}.\\ 
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

You may use double index for your sequence.

$$ a_{k,n}=\frac{2(k+1)(3^n)-1}{5}$$

That will cover all your terms.